# Purpose of App_Start on MVC3 (gets created with Ninject.MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

As per Ninject MVC3 instruction below, App_Start folder gets created via Nuget Package:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

When does the file under App_Start gets executed? As I've not seen anything on Global.asax calling the classes found under App_Start folder.

Also, is there an advantage of keeping files under this directory rather than global.asax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Ninject specifically, but the general idea behind *App_Start* is to be able to install/uninstall nuget packages that use Application_Start code, without touching Global.asax.cs.

In my opinion, it should be named *App_Events*.  If packages add code for Application_BeginRequest, _EndRequest, _Error, etc. then *App_Start* doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Well. Nothing :) It's just convention.

The interesting part is `WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod` in the code file. It tell's ASP.NET to run the specified method.